# Smarter way of constructing query

Tags: sql, node.js, algorithm

In my node.js module, I have some data in an array which I need to construct a query:

```
var valueClause = "(fieldA = '" + data.fieldA + "' AND fieldB = '";
var whereClause = ' WHERE ';
var hasAdded = false;

data.accounts.forEach(function (account) {
    whereClause += valueClause + account.fieldB + "') OR ";
    hasAdded = true;
})

if (hasAdded) {
    // remove OR
    whereClause = whereClause.substring(0, whereClause.length - 3);

    // use the whereClause in the query
    ...
}
```

At the end of the above codes, if I have 2 accounts, I have whereClause:

' WHERE (fieldA = 'abcde' AND fieldB = '0003') OR (fieldA = 'abcde' AND fieldB = '0002') OR

I always have to remove the last ' OR' bit.

Is there a smarter way to construct the above?

Answer (score 2):

Since the value of fieldA seems to be fix in the loop you could write this query

```
  WHERE fieldA = 'abcde' AND fieldB IN ('0002','0003')
```

Since you have no prepared SQL Statement, where you could use the Array directly, you have to join the values similar to yout approach.

If guaranteed at lest one value exists I concatenate in the loop always with leading comma and use substr(1) of the value